# Can IFS be replaced in excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, ifs

I am using office 365 and I am creating a WB for someone who is using excel 2016. My code inserts a "IFS" formula in all the cells of a column to the last row.  The issues is IFS is not available in 2016 so the code fails for them but works for me. Is there a way to change the following code to work in 2016?  When they run the macro the get #NAME?

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFS(RC[-2]=""2nd Shift 1.05"",""2"", RC[-2]=""2nd Shift     
Overtime"",""2"",TRUE,"""")" 
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & Lastrow)
Range("E2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: use a standard IF with OR: `IF(OR(E2 = "2nd Shift 1.05",E2="2nd Shift     
Overtime"),2,"")`   I will let you convert it to vba.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be shortened to:

```
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("G2:G" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(OR(E2 = ""2nd Shift 1.05"",E2=""2nd Shift Overtime""),2,"""")"
```

Comment: Thanks guys - I actually went in a different direction which seems to work better. I guessing it could probably be shortened as well... Im self taught and tend to do things the long way.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dim LastCall As Long
    Dim y As Long
    LastCall = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 2 To LastCall
        If Range("E" & y).Value = "2nd Shift 1.05" Then
            Range("G" & y).Value = "2"
    End If
    Next y

    LastCall = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 2 To LastCall
        If Range("E" & y).Value = "2nd Shift Overtime" Then
            Range("G" & y).Value = "2"
    End If
    Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry about that - was having issues with posting the code as it should look